# How to find all build plans I have created?

Tags: bamboo

I created a build plan in Bamboo recently for something I'm working on. I accidentally created it within the wrong project. We have so many projects with so many plans each that I lost the plan I had created in the wrong spot.

Fortunately, I just found the plan. I wasted too much time and effort looking for it though since we have so many plans with similar names since we have lots of similar projects.

How could I have done a search by plan creator so that I could see all plans created by me?

I have Googled various things, including "bamboo find plans I've created" and "bamboo search by plan creator" and others, but everything turns up results about creating plans or other unrelated pages.

Answer (score 1):

This capability is not built into Bamboo as of their latest version 6.10.  The only auditing I am aware of it an audit log for task changes.

You may be able to create something custom using the [rest API](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bamboo/bamboo-rest-resources/) though.